# Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen "sosehr" and "so sehr"?

Tags: meaning, difference

*Sosehr* ist, laut mehreren Wörterbüchern, eine Konjunktion. Ein Beispiel ist:

> *Sosehr* ich Mozart respektiere, finde ich seine Produktivität bei moll-Streichquarteten vorwerfbar spärlich.

Aus jedem solcher Wörterbucheinträge lässt sich herleiten, dass *sosehr* was ganz anders ist als *so sehr*. Nirgends in deutschen Wörterbüchern steht ein Eintrag zu *so sehr*.

Neulich fand ich einen Satz, der so strukturiert ist:

> So schön der Abend war, **sosehr** ich Hanna auch mochte, **so sehr** war auch damals schon klar: *(für die Frage irrelevante Erklärung folgt)*.

Ich gehe davon aus, dass das zusammengestellte *sosehr* durch *wie sehr ... auch* ersetzen werden darf (oder eben nicht, aber deren Bedeutungen weichen nicht viel voneinander ab). Und dass das getrennte *so sehr* etwas Gegenteiliges antizipiert, dessen »Magnitude« mit dem Hanna-Mögen zu vergleichen wäre (*sehr* klar. Wie klar? So sehr, wie das *Ich* Hanna mochte, angeblich viel).

**Frage**: Ich kann vermuten, dass ich entweder falsch oder noch unvollständig diesen Unterschied verstehe und dass ich noch viel dazu lernen könnte. Und so bitte ich um eine entsprechende Erklärung.

Comment: @c.p. Ich habe soeben auf die Frage geantwortet. Da dies meine erste Frage in dieser Community ist, würde ich Feedback begrüßen (bspw. Antworten auf Fragen wie "Ist der Sachverhalt deutlich (genug) dargestellt worden?", "Ist die Antwort vollständig?", etc.). Vielen Dank im Voraus!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Der Unterschied ist relativ zügig erklärt.

*"So sehr"* könnte durch etwas wie *"dermaßen"* (Adv.) ersetzt werden, es wird verwendet um der vorangegangenen oder nachfolgenden Aussage Nachdruck zu verleihen. Eine Möglichkeit der Verwendung wäre folgendes Beispiel:

> Das Wetter in Deutschland geht mir **dermaßen** auf den Zeiger.
>
> Das Wetter in Deutschland geht mir **so sehr** auf den Zeiger.

*"Sosehr"* (Konj.) hingegen findet Verwendung in Sätzen wie den folgenden, und kann - wie bereits richtig angenommen - auch durch *"wie sehr .. auch"* ersetzt werden:

> **Sosehr** ich Deutschland auch schätze, das Wetter ist grauenhaft.
>
> **Wie sehr** ich Deutschland auch schätze, das Wetter ist grauenhaft.

---

Zusammenfassend lässt sich sagen, dass *"so sehr"* letztlich lediglich eine stärkere Form von *"sehr"* ist, und beispielsweise durch *"dermaßen"*, *"massiv"* etc. ersetzt werden kann.

Unter Zuhilfenahme von Online-Duden wie bspw. Duden.de lassen sich derartige Unterschiede *relativ* leicht erschließen. Das Suchergebnis der Suche nach ["so sehr"](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/so%20sehr) beinhaltet auch Einträge, die "so sehr" beinhalten, nicht aber hauptsächlich thematisieren, wie - unter anderem - der Eintrag zu ["dermaßen"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dermaszen).

Comment: Willkommen! ... +1, weil es mir eine gute Erklärung zu sein schient. Jedoch bin ich nicht so sicher, dass es den Duden-Eintrag zu *so sehr* gibt. Zwar findet die Duden-Suchmaschine *so* und *sehr*. Beim *sehr-Eintrag* steht aber *so sehr* nur als Beispiel.  Nun, Dein Zweiter Kommentar (zu *dermaßen*) stimmt, und der *dermaßen*-Eintrag thematisiert es doch. Der Link dazu erscheint aber erst auf dem 13. Platz der Duden-Suche (was meine Frage hier rechtfertigt).

Comment: @c.p. Zunächst einmal vielen Dank! Nein, einen Duden-Eintrag zu *so sehr* gibt es tatsächlich nicht. Worauf ich hinauswollte war das Durchsuchen anderer Einträge, wie eben auch *dermaßen*. Dieser ist zwar auf dem 13. Platz, aber immerhin noch auf der 1. Seite (von 21). Im Allgemeinen kann man die Suchergebnisse jedoch recht schnell überfliegen (notfalls unter Zuhilfenahme der Browser-Suchfunktion), und findet so in den meisten Fällen immerhin etwas. :)