# Phonetischer Unterschied zwischen "sosehr" and "so sehr"

Tags: phonetics

[In einer anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33945/unterschied-zwischen-sosehr-and-so-sehr?noredirect=1#comment83860_33945) habe ich nach dem Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen *sosehr* und *so sehr* gefragt.
Ergänzend dazu interessiert mich, inwiefern die beiden phonetisch einen Unterschied aufweisen.
Wäre die erste Variante (*sosehr*) [zoˈzeːɐ̯], mit Betonung auf *e*? Wie wäre dann die zweite Variante? Genügt da eine Trennung [zo] [zeːɐ̯]?

Comment: Was ist *sosehr*? Ich habe diese Worte noch nie zusammengeschrieben gesehen.

Comment: @KilianFoth Falls du "so sehr" schon mal als Konjunktion verwendet hast, wird's Zeit, dass du es besser als "[sosehr](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sosehr)" schreibst.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es gibt keinen Unterschied in der Aussprache zwischen der Konjunktion *sosehr* und der adverbialen Wendung *so sehr*.

Es kann natürlich vorkommen, dass der Betonung halber ein Vokal in der adverbialen Wendung langgezogen wird — in aller Regel wohl das *O* in *so*. Ansonsten ist aber phonetisch kein Unterschied aufzuweisen.

---

Während die Konjunktion stets an erster Position des Satzes ist, kann die adverbiale Wendung auch dort stehen. Dein Beispiel aus der verlinkten Frage zeigt dies. In diesem Fall kann man die Konjunktion von der adverbialen Wendung einzig durch die allgemeine Anordnung der Satzelemente ausmachen. Die Konjunktion ist stets vom Subjekt gefolgt, während hinter der adverbiale Wendung das zugehörige Verb steht.
Hier eine Modifikation deines Beispiels, die es — denke ich — sehr anschaulich zeigt.

> Sosehr ich Hanna auch mochte, so sehr mochte ich auch Tina.

*Sosehr* ist strikt genommen eine Subjunktion (untergeordnete Konjunktion), daher steht das Verb in einem mit *sosehr* eingeleiteten Teilsatz an letzter Stelle.
Der andere Teil ist ein Hauptsatz. Das Verb steht an zweiter Stelle und der gewöhnliche Satzbau ist S-P-O. Die adverbiale Wendung wurde hier an erste Stelle verschoben und verdrängt somit das Subjekt an die dritte Position.

> Ich mochte auch Tina so sehr. -> So sehr mochte ich auch Tina.